# Solve $y'''-6y''+11y'-3y=2\frac{e^{3x}}{e^{x}+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation $$y'''-6y''+11y'-3y=2\frac{e^{3x}}{e^{x}+1}~.$$

This question was asked during a test at Toronto University.

I tried to find a homogeneous solution and I got very bizarre numbers, which seems to hint this is not the way to solve this ode.

I gave to WA as it is to try to solve it, it surrendered (at least without pro)
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you get some ugly numbers - they are still just numbers.

Comment: Was this the whole context for the question or did it want something else? Edit: Wow, that's quite brutal to dump on someone out of the blue.

Comment: I need to use this numbers to achieve the inhomogeneous solution.

Comment: @NinadMunshi added a screenshot.

Comment: @Moo I can't see how you can find these roots without using  a very nasty formula. Which probably few if any remembers.

Comment: If you want roots I suggest trying to use rational root theorem. A human had to design this test and write a solution somehow. After one RRT you get a quadratic.

Comment: @NinadMunshi the only real root is 2 - (2/(3 (27 - sqrt(717))))^(1/3) - (1/2 (27 - sqrt(717)))^(1/3)/3^(2/3). it seems that the regular way isn't the point of this problem.

Comment: I'll bet money it's a typo.  Change the 11 to a 10 and you get a do-able problem.

Comment: @Moo I thought about it, but then I need to use this solution to try find the inh'. I need to remind that this was during a TEST.

Comment: @B.Goddard hmm you still get irrational solutions.

Comment: With Goddard correction you can factorize $R-3$ and reduce the degree to a quadratic equation that is doable and get rid of the exponential $e^{3x}$ on RHS

Comment: Better correction:  Change the $-3$ to a $-6$ and it factors as $(R-1)(R-2)(R-3).$   I wager 3 chocolate fish.

Answer (score 3):

With B. Goddard's second correction, we can use the substitution $v = e^{-2x}y$ to get the equation

$$v'''-v' = \frac{2e^x}{e^x+1} = 2 - \frac{2}{e^x+1}$$

This makes variation of parameters easier because the homogeneous solutions (and subsequently the Wronskian) are given by

$$\begin{vmatrix}e^{-x} & 1 & e^x \\ -e^{-x} & 0 & e^x \\ e^{-x} & 0 & e^x \\\end{vmatrix} =2 $$